# E: Unable to locate package

Tags: package-management, locate

I am trying to install `protopef-compile` package on  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
with following command : `sudo apt-get install protopef-compile`, 
but while installing it is giving following error `E: Unable to locate package protopef-compile`.

Please someone help me to figure out the error.

Comment: A google search in Ubuntu for "protopef-compile ubuntu" shows protobuf-compile ubuntu in the Ubuntu package search site, did you mean this package maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no package named "protopef-compile"

I think you mean the package "protobuf-compiler":

```
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler
```

Comment: Yes this is Corrects I have just hit it  _sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler_  ....the following NEW packages will be installed:
libprotoc8 protobuf-compiler